# Wondering how to achieve this blur text effect, hopefully in Sketch

Tags: text, blur, sketch-app

[image: http://cl.ly/image/2Y1N0G283g1f]
Is there any way to easily generate this?
thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I just spent some time recreating this in Sketch for you. If you'd like to check out the raw file you can download it here: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/nxtj6htricmn7en/RdHzDCRIR6

Basically I've cloned the letter multiple times and applied a motion blur and opacity to achieve a similar effect. If I was aiming for pixel-perfection I'd've scaled each shadow letter appropriately to recreate the proper perspective that each shadow has in the original.

As a side note, the font is Avenir Next Regular.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Based on the Userguide I would use Motion Blur. Without knowing how Sketch works it looks like you might need to make the letters as separate outlines/objects whatever they're called in this particular software. Then adjust the motion blur a little on each one to give the effect of them all coming from one focal point.

The userguide doesn't really give details on how or where the blur tool is but here's the page: http://www.bohemiancoding.com/sketch/help/manual/layer-styling/

Answer (score 0):

*One* way to do this is **manually**: make several layers (10 or more), each with the "rise" text, but the bottom layer is the smallest size and the top layer is the final size of the text.

Each layer, slightly enlarge the text and perhaps slightly increase the tracking, and then blur slightly. Set each layer to "overlay" or "lighten" mode. Motion blur (if available) in the direction of movement is recommended, but this method is mostly tool agnostic.

Shift layers manually to tweak positioning. Below is a sample with 4 or 5 levels and very little tweaking. The typeface is Comic Sans, *which should be in every designer's toolbox*.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In Adobe Fireworks, this is quite easily achievable.

You need to download and install this free (awesome) extension http://fireworks.abeall.com/extensions/#Path

- Start with the desired font. (make sure your're happy with it before you proceed) (fig.1)
- Make a duplicate and put it beneath in the layer-stack
- Convert duplicate to paths (ctrl + shift + p) and ungroup (ctrl + shift + g)
- Union these ungrouped paths (Modify >> Combine Path >> Union )
- Extrude paths using the path panel (fig.2)
- Set the Opacity and add a little Gaussian Blur.
- Make any further changes, otherwise you're done (fig.3)

---

Fig.1

[image: Set the font and stuff]

Fig.2

[image: Extrude the paths]

Fig.3

[image: See the typography you made]